# How to INNER JOIN on non-empty values BUT AT THE SAME TIME LEFT JOIN on empty values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, inner-join

It seems that I need a `MAGIC JOIN` that should work as `INNER JOIN` on non-empty values but at the same time work as `LEFT JOIN` on empty values. By "empty" I mean a non-null zero-length `char` value, like this: `''`.

I have table `Customers`:

```
CustomerCode    Customer_AddressCode
CC01            AC01
CC02            somebullcrap
CC03
CC04            AC02
CC05
```

and `Addresses`:

```
AddressCode    AddressValue
AC01           City 01
AC02           City 02
AC03           City 03
AC04           City 04
AC05           City 05
```

The desired output is like this:

```
CustomerCode  AddressValue
CC01          City 01
CC03          NULL
CC04          City 04
CC05          NULL
```

so it would omit address with code `somebullcrap` that does not exist in `Addresses` table.

The best I could think of is this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerCode, a.AddressValue
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON a.AddressCode = c.Customer_AddressCode
WHERE c.Customer_AddressCode = ''
OR c.Customer_AddressCode IN
(
    SELECT AddressCode
    FROM Address
)
```

Is there any more elegant solution to this?

**And yes, I do know about nullable foreign keys.** I'm just asking about solution without altering tables / making temp tables / modifying existing table data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not

```
SELECT c.CustomerCode, a.AddressValue
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Addresses a 
   ON a.AddressCode = c.Customer_AddressCode
WHERE c.Customer_AddressCode = ''
   OR a.AddressValue IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Execution Plan-wise, this is the "most elegant".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just a left join, given that there is no address with an empty string as a code in your addresses table.  I think that this would give you the desired results:

```
SELECT c.CustomerCode, a.AddressValue
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON a.AddressCode = c.Customer_AddressCode
```

Why is there no CHECK on the foreign key between customers and addresses?

Comment: Noting that I now see in the question that you want to totally omit the customer record with somebullcrap as the address id. This would not work for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to handle the empty strings ( '' ), you can use a simple

```
CASE Customer_AddressCode='' THEN NULL ELSE Customer_AddressCode END
```

to cast your empty strings to a real `NULL` value.
Then, a simple `LEFT JOIN` like this :

```
SELECT c.CustomerCode, a.AddressValue
FROM 
(SELECT 
    CustomerCode, 
    CASE Customer_AddressCode='' THEN NULL ELSE Customer_AddressCode END AdCode
FROM Customers) c
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON (a.AddressCode = c.AdCode OR c.AdCode is null)
```

The `c.AdCode is null` condition will allow empty values in the result while filtering the "somebullcrap" you don't seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

EricZ's is probably the most elegant approach that will return the correct results, but just as an exercise in alternatives:

```
SELECT  c.CustomerCode
      , a.AddressValue FROM    Customers c
        JOIN ( SELECT   AddressCode
                      , AddressValue
               FROM     Addresses
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   ''
                      , NULL
             ) a ON a.AddressCode = c.Customer_AddressCode
```